# R: ggplot stacked bar graph legend upside down

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a stacked bar graph:

```
df1 <- data.frame(sex       = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
                 time       = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
                 total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42))
# Stacked bar graph -- this is not what I want
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Which appears to be:
[image]

I want the sex legend on the right to correspond with the stack order on the left, i.e., red on the bottom and blue on top, how can I do that?

Comment: I found a large number of prior questions using the search terms: `[r] geom_bar order legend`. If you really had done some searching and looked through the candidates, then you should describe how they failed to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also add either of these (they're equivalent):

```
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

From the [Cookbook for R Graphics](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Male","Female"))
```

Worked for me